# What is the benefit to using a static library over including a header file?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

Sorry if this is a noobish question, but here it is anyway.

So I followed [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx) on MSDN about creating and using static libraries.

Let's assume you have a Static Library `fooLib`, and a Program `barExec`, that uses `fooLib`

According to the tutorial, or at least my interpretation of it, in the source code for `barExec`, you have to `#include` the header file used to compile `fooLib` (`fooLib.h`, in my case).

So the code that I have in `barExec` is as follows:

```
// barExec.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "fooLib.h"

// Rest of my program here.
```

My question is, Why should I bother going through all the extra hassle of creating `fooLib` in the first place, especially since I had to write `fooLib.cpp` anyway? Is there a benefit to creating the `fooLib` library, when I could just `#include "fooLib.h"` directly?

Comment: It's not either/or. You always need the header file, regardless of whether you link to a static or a dynamic library.

Comment: @EJP:
Which is why I'm wondering if it makes more sense to just use the .h and .cpp files directly, as opposed to going through all the (seemingly pointless) work of compiling them into a library.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You really ought to make that into an answer. *nudge nudge*

Comment: Well if you read a tutorial about creating static libraries, you're going to encounter instructions about how to create statuc libraries. If you don't want to create static libraries, don't. Nobody is forcing you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a false dichotomy in your question. A static library is not an alternative to a header. There are, off the top of my head, 3 alternatives to a static library.

1. A dynamic library. A compiled library that is seperate from the executable, which is loaded at runtime.
2. One or more object files. An object file being a compiled translation unit (typically, a single compiled c++ source file, although it depends upon how you compile)
3. One or more c++ source files.

In all cases, you still need your headers (or alternatively, you can just declare the functions and types you need to use, if there aren't too many, and you know the right signatures).

Option 2 is essentially what a static library is. The only difference is, that the object files are conveniently packed up into a single file. This makes distributing and using the library at least a little bit easier. For example, if you have a library with 10 object files which you want to use, linking it might look something like this:

```
g++ main.o foo1.o foo2.o foo3.o foo4.o foo5.o foo6.o foo7.o foo8.o foo9.o foo10.o
```

whereas if you put it in a static library, the linking invocation might look a lot simpler:

```
g++ main.o -lfoo
```

Option 3 is the precursor to option 2. If you have one or more c++ source files, after you compile them, you will have one or more object files (although most toolchains will allow you to combine the compiling and linking into one step, in which case no object files will appear on disk). If you have a large library that you plan to use in many projects, you may not want to recompile it for every one of those projects. So you may opt for option 2. And if that results in a lot of object files, you may find it convenient to opt for a static library.

Comment: isn't `-lfoo` a shared library linking syntax? for more accurate example I think you should write `g++ main.o foo.a`

Answer (score 0):

A header file provides the declarations of functions and variables only. It does not provide the implementations of the functions and definitions of variables. The latter can be found in another .cpp file or a library, which can be a static library or a dynamic library.

Comment: In my case, I have a `fooLib.cpp` which includes its header. Probably should've made that clear... I'll edit that in.

Comment: @GabeEvans, it's possible to put the object code corresponding to `fooLib.cpp` in a library and then link the library. You can also add `fooLib.cpp` to your project and then you won't need to link the library.

Comment: Okay, but is there a reason or benefit to creating the library and linking it to my project when all the code to use the library's functions is already available in the "raw" .cpp and .h files?

Comment: If the code corresponding to those files can be used in multiple Projects, it makes sense to put them in a library. Otherwise, it is not very useful.

Comment: @GabeEvans Depends on how many cpp files make up your library. Imagine you have hundreds/thousands of files that constitutes a library, say, OpenCV, etc. Now, would you want to include all those files into your project and manage them? Or would you rather just include the headers for the one or two library files in your code and link against the library(ies)?